# Blender with Niftools addon, how can I export an fbx file with a texture linked to it?

Tags: uv, export, .fbx

I'm trying to export nif models to fbx models using NifTools addon, when I import the nif model I get to see the name of the texture, here's an example: [image]
But when I try to export it to fbx I get this:[image]
The name of the texture is gone, the only thing remaining is a "Box02" which is the name of the mesh I'm using.

So when I need to load a fbx model on another program I eventually need to manually indicate what is the right texture for this model, and this can be very troublesome as I'm trying create a scene with multiple models.

**Note:** I've already tried exporting the nif model with the path mode set to "Copy" and activate the Embed Textures option, but this doesn't seem to be working as my FBX file keeps missing the texture data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the texture is not set as a material for the object, but is still showing up in Texture Paint mode because it is in the tool’s active slot. Was the NIFtools addon originally designed for 2.79?

Anyway, you need to actually set up the texture as a material in Object or Edit mode. More on the subject can be found here: [Blender Manual: Materials, Index](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm not sure about the addon version, but I think it is as the version I'm using had it's last update only one month ago. I think it's best to create a algorithm in this case to create a file with the model-texture relation from the nif files as there are a lot of models.